# Using ImageMagick in R

Tags: r, imagemagick

I have followed all procedures to install ImageMagick, and I got that test.gif which contains an old guy with a magic stick. However, when I use it in RStudio, the error message is the same as before:

In im.convert(img.files, output = path.expand(movie.name), convert = convert,  :
  Please install ImageMagick first or put its bin path into the system PATH variable

Here is my code:

```
library(animation)
saveGIF({
  for (i in 1:4){
    if(i==1){
      print(a)
    }
    if(i==2){
      print(b)
    }
    if(i==3){
      print(c)
    }
    else{print(d)}
    }
}, interval = .2, movie.name="test.gif")
```

Comment: Where did you install `imagemagick`? Perhaps you chose to not add its installation to your system (or user) `PATH`. Either way, find out where you installed it (OS-dependent) and compare that with the output of `Sys.getenv("PATH")` in R.

Comment: When I restart the Rstudio, I can use that function...It is really weird...I ran your command, but it showed     "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin"

Comment: One possibility is you installed ImageMagick 7 and Rstudio needs ImageMagick 6. What version of ImageMagick did you install?

Comment: In your Terminal, run `which convert` and you will see where it is installed. Make sure that the directory containing `convert` is in your PATH inside R.

Comment: Thank you all! I finally figure it out! I just added a specific address to movie.name variable.